# How to say 'in 10 minutes' as in 'the bus comes in 10 minutes'?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

Would the sentence below make sense?

> バスがじゅっぷんにきます。

Comment: じゅっぷんにきます might sound like 'the bus comes at hh:10'. Let's say you are waiting for a bus at 09:55, then if you say "バスがじゅっぷんにきます", your friends  probably think that the bus is coming at 10:10.

Answer (score 4):

You would say

> バスは[１０分]{じっぷん(じゅっぷん)}[後]{ご}に来ます。
>   or バスは（[後]{あと}）１０分で来ます。

Comment: The [後]{あと} in the 2nd sentence is optional. The 2nd sentence sounds more casual than the 1st. For the two readings of 10分, see [this thread](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/11213/what-is-the-proper-pronunciation-for-%E5%8D%81%E5%88%86-%EF%BC%91%EF%BC%90%E5%88%86-%E3%81%98%E3%81%A3%E3%81%B7%E3%82%93-or-%E3%81%98%E3%82%85%E3%81%A3%E3%81%B7%E3%82%93)

Comment: As I have put below in my answer below, 後10分 is  incorrect.

Comment: @paullb この[辞書](http://ejje.weblio.jp/sentence/content/%E3%81%82%E3%81%A8%E3%80%80%E5%88%86%E3%81%A7)にはこんな例文がありますが。「私はあと10分でそこに着きます。I will arrive there in 10 minutes. 」「電車はあと五分で到着の予定です。The train is due to arrive here in 5 minutes.」[このページ](http://www.eijiro.jp/v95.htm)にも、「The bus will be here in __ minutes. あと＿分でバスが来ます。」とありますが、どうして「あと１０分で」はいけないんですか？

Answer (score 2):

I would usually use `後｛ご｝`, as an indication of what is to come :

> バスが十分｛じゅっぷん｝後｛ご｝に来{き}ます。

Another example :

> 飛行機{ひこうき}は１０分[後]｛ご｝に離陸｛りりく｝します。

Maybe you also know `後｛あと｝で` as a way to say, `afterwards, in a while`, this is the same kanji. You can use it this way :

> 電車｛でんしゃ｝は後｛あと｝五分で発車｛はっしゃ｝します。

Answer (score 0):

You could say

> バスは[10分]{じゅっぷん}後{ご}に来{き}ます。

Or a slightly more formal

> バスは[10分]{じゅっぷん}後{ご}に到着{とうちゃく}します。

EDIT:
I asked my Japanese teacher about this (as it came up somewhere else) the following clarification was made:

BAD: 後２０分に (This phrasing is typically used for an ongoing action that has already started)

GOOD: ２０分後に (This specifies a time point in the future)

I have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: After checking with my Japanese teacher I discovered I had it wrong. Made changes accordingly.

Comment: 1. Did your teacher tell you that the 後 in １０分後に is read only as あと, not ご?  2. Did your teacher tell you that 後２０分**に** is grammatically correct and can be used in certain context?

Comment: @Choco In fact she did, I forgot to fix the furigana. Fixed now. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: What, your teacher said 後２０分「に」 is grammatically correct? Is she a native speaker?

Comment: @Choco I genuinely forget if she said にor で the focus was on the 20分 part as I had wrote it in a text message and she was correcting me.