# How to express future times?

Tags: particles, time

I'm a little confused on how exactly I would say "I'm going to Japan in 2 months." I don't want to make it seem like I'm saying "I'm going to Japan for 2 months"

What would be the difference between those two sentences?

Here's what I have ２ヶ月に日本へ行きます。

If I dropped the particle に, would that indicate I am going for 2 months? Or would it still indicate in 2 months I would be going.

Thank you!

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/33945/5010

Comment: You could just slap a 後 (read as ご) on the end of 2ヶ月 if you want to be more explicit.

Comment: Also related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/24516/9831