# Translating "In 10 years, I might be living in Japan."

Tags: grammar, translation, time

Regarding periods of time, I know that for [one-time-event verbs](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/24516/how-to-say-in-10-minutes-as-in-the-bus-comes-in-10-minutes), there are a few options. For example, "I'll move in 10 years" could be 「10年後にひっこす」「10年でひっこす」「あと10年でひっこす」.

[This link](https://hinative.com/questions/24791385) gives some conflicting examples. First of all, whether or not the speaker is living in Japan now, apparently makes a difference? I'm unclear why that is. Also, I'd think we'd use 「住んでいる」, but one Japanese person says 「住む」 is OK.

Which of these are correct, and do they imply the person lives in Japan now or not (and why)?

「(10年後・10年後に・10年・10年で・あと10年・あと10年で)、日本に(住む・住んでいる)かもしれません。」

Lastly, in which phrases is it OK to add/substitute 以内に?

Answer (score 2):

Probably the most natural is

- 10年後、日本に住んでいるかもしれません。

Other possibilities are

- 10年後(に)、日本に(住む・住んでいる)かもしれません。

Use of 住む sounds less common, but seems the same to me in terms of meaning. As for the particle after 10年後, は or には could be used as well.

---

**(あと)10年**

These mean the duration of 10 years. So it implies that the state is ongoing.

- 10年、日本に住むかもしれません means *I may live in Japan 10 years (The duration I live in Japan could be 10 years)*. It's a bit hard to imagine in what situation such an utterance is made.
- あと10年,... would imply you're living in Japan and also another 10 years.

**(あと)10年で**

Probably because [で](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%A7/#jn-148951) means 期限, it comes more naturally with one-time event/instantaneous verbs. As such, it does not work with 住む/住んでいる.

Comment: Thank you. Out of curiosity, this conflicts with some answers from (supposedly) native speakers at the Hinative link in my post - at least one says 「あと10年で」 (using both あと and で) is acceptable & natural. But you say で "does not work" here. Can you explain?

Comment: @Hikonyan 10年で is most naturally used like 10年でサグラダファミリアが完成するかもしれません. There's felt some completion. So if the speaker is planning a long term project of moving to Japan, 10年で could be used (that is, very literally 10年で日本に住んでいるかもしれません would be *I may finally start living in Japan in 10 years*) - which is just unlikely to me.