# Why use 「一〇点」 instead of 「十点」 and how do I read it?

Tags: readings, numbers

I'm reading the Japanese version of *Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone*. When Oliver Wood is explaining Quidditch rules to Harry, he says:

> 輪に入るたびに一〇点だ。

Why say 「一〇点」 instead of 「十点」? How do I read it? 「イチゼロテン」?「ジュウテン」？「Tenてん」？

Is this something specific to sports? The only sport I follow is football, and since I have heard weird things like commentators saying 「いちななーいちはち」 for the '17-'18 Premier League season, I suspect that might be the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you're reading the book on paper (or Kindle-like terminal), where the text is written vertically. In *vertical mode*, the positional notation of *kanji numerals* are used as much as how Arabic numerals are used in horizontal mode.

> 一〇点 *10 points* vs. 十点 *ten points*

It doesn't affect the pronunciation, so you're just going to read it out じゅってん (or じってん, prescriptively). Something like いちぜろてん is rarely used unless you're a pilot or the base is other than ten.

See also:

- [Are kanji typically used in times and dates?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/17423/7810)
- [What is the proper pronunciation for 十分/１０分? じっぷん or じゅっぷん?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/11213/7810)
- [Why is 1st floor written as ikkai いっかい?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/40325/7810)

Comment: Yes, it's on a Kindle with vertical text. Thanks!